# Change one property in Array of objects Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am writing small program which is supposed to simulate cooking. I have an array of objects which are ingredients. Each ingredient has amount and name. I need to implement method which will decrease the amount of ingredient each time it is used. I have a class Kitchen where ingredients are stored in an array. I am new to Ruby, I really don't know how to change single property of a single object inside Array. Here's what I have and what does not compile:

```
def get_ingredient(name, count)
 totalIngredientsCount = @ingredients.inject(0){|count, p| count + p.count.to_f}

if (@ingredients.empty? == 0 || totalIngredientsCount == 0)
  puts("Kitchen is empty")
else
  {
      @ingredients.collect! { |i|
        if (i.name == name) then
          i.count = i.count - count #???
        else
          puts 'There is no ingredient with given name'
        end
      }
  }
end
end

class Ingredient
  def initialize(name, count)
    @name = name
    @count = count
  end

  attr_accessor :count
  attr_reader :name

end
```

Comment: Maybe this problem is too big for you. Have you tried something smaller and simpler?

Comment: How else can I approach this? This is my assignment. I know a thing or two about programming I just have to use Ruby for this, which in general wouldn't be my first choice...

Comment: If I were you, I'd pay someone to watch them code the thing for me. And then answer my questions about the code (so that I'm able to defend my assignment later).

Comment: Have you considered using a Hash instead of an array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", including the linked pages, and "[mcve]" then “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. Your code doesn't demonstrate a problem, it's just not complete so you need to finish writing it, then ask a specific question about whatever problem you encounter. Try reading the [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html) documentation if you want to learn how they work or read some tutorials.

Comment: @theTinMan I went through Array documentation. It just gives examples on arrays of integers and so on. If I could easily google answer I wouldn't bother people there

Comment: Then you didn't read the documentation. [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [`[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) specifically tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you have tried but I would suggest you break down your problem into tiny discreet sets, solve said sets one at a time, and then finally put them together.

So using your question as example, I would do the doing:

```
    Problem 1: 
      - I have an array of objects which are ingredients. 
        - array_of_objects = []

      - Each ingredient has amount and name.
        - the fact that ingredients have an amount and name makes me think of a key value object. So use a hash maybe? 
        - one_ingredient = {}
          - I need a way to key track of an ingredient by name so add key name and set its value. 
             one_ingredient[:name] = "apple"
             one_ingredient[:amount] = 2

    - I need to put this ingredient into the array_of_objects
      - array_of_objects.push one_ingredient
         - this returns a data structure that looks like this: 
               [ {name: "apple, amount: 2} ]
```

Can you see what is going on? The next thing you want to do is look in the `Array` and `Hash` classes in Ruby to see how you can manipulate data structures. Think of how do I iterate an `Array` and/or a `Hash`.

For example,let's look at [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-each) method in Ruby's `Array` class. If you click on the link, you see that you can iterate through an array by calling each on it and thus gain access to objects within the array. So we can do something like this:

```
    array_of_objects.each do |object|
     # each yields to a block and inside the block you have access 
     # to the object that has been yielded to each. Basically, if 
     # you use `pry` or debugger you can stop your code here, inspect
     # your object, and also see what methods you can call on your 
     # object. 

     # since your object is a hash, you should try calling `each` on 
     # it.  I believe Ruby Hashes have an each method - check to be    
     # sure. Then play around and see how you can access keys and 
     # values in a hash, and change their respective values.    
    end
```

You can start with simple methods like `each` or `each_with_key`. Play around with those.

Once you figure that out, then you can begin to think of building a `class` that puts all these concepts together. If you can't think through a step then you can try asking again on Stackoverflow BUT be very specific (and I know this is hard when one isn't very familar with a language but just try and describe the problem you are having in plain English).

Hope this helps. Good luck :)